# How to disable drag item in QWebView

Tags: css, qt, qwebview

How to disable the mouse press event while user can drag any item for QwebView without mousepressevent() function. because i am not promote a QWebView class .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to disable dropping anything *into* the QWebView or disable dragging anything *out of* the QWebView?

Comment: yes,Drop functionality is to OK with AcceptDropFunction(True) for QwebView class. but drag property is not get in qwebview.